# Align a chapter* title with a chapter title in memoir

Tags: vertical-alignment, memoir, chapters

I want to align chapter*-title with chapter-title in memoir, as show in the following

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |  Chapter 1                      |
|  -----------------------------  |  -----------------------------  |
|  Test One                       |  Test Two                       |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
|                                 |                                 |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I know I should use the `\makechapterstyle` but I don't know how:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{stack}
{
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}{\hrule\vspace{0.6\midchapskip}\chaptitlefont}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{\par\vspace{\midchapskip}}
}
\chapterstyle{stack}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test One}

\chapter{Test Two}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best would be to place a `\strut` in places where you have no text (specifically `\printchapternonum`). For completeness, it's actually easiest to add this - a `\strut` - to all definitions of `\chapnamefont` and `\chaptitlefont`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\makechapterstyle{stack}
{
  \renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
  \def\chapterheadstart{\vspace*{\beforechapskip}}
  \addtodef{\chapnamefont}{}{\strut}
  \addtodef{\chaptitlefont}{}{\strut}
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\hrule \par\chaptitlefont ##1\par}
  \renewcommand{\printchapternonum}{\chapnamefont\par}
}
\chapterstyle{stack}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Test One}

\chapter{Test Two}

\end{document}
```

`\addtodef{<macro>}{<before>}{<after>}` is provided by [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) as an extension of the regular kernel `\g@addto@macro`.